# How to prevent Multiple time form submission on clicking Enter button in form validation

Tags: javascript, formvalidation-plugin, jquery-form-validator

I am using form validation in my application. When I press enter multiple times the form gets submitted multiple times.

Here is my code:

```
  $.validate({
        modules: 'security',
        form: '#import-form',
        validateOnBlur: false,
        errorMessagePosition: 'element', 
        scrollToTopOnError: false,
        language: {
            requiredFields: "This field is required."
        },
        onSuccess: function ($form) {
            submitjob();
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Please let me know how to prevent multiple time form submission on pressing enter key. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ***preventDefault()*** in **onSuccess**? Like

```
 $.validate({
        modules: 'security',
        form: '#import-form',
        validateOnBlur: false,
        errorMessagePosition: 'element', 
        scrollToTopOnError: false,
        language: {
            requiredFields: "This field is required."
        },
        onSuccess: function ($form) {
            $form.preventDefault();
            submitjob();
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Yes Albert, I have tried the same but it doesn't works. Form gets submitted multiple times only.

Comment: It is possible that your HTML <form> **action** attribute has a value. Try to leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please use submitHandler callback instead of onSuccesscallback

```
$.validate({
        modules: 'security',
        form: '#import-form',
        validateOnBlur: false,
        errorMessagePosition: 'element', 
        scrollToTopOnError: false,
        language: {
            requiredFields: "This field is required."
        },
        submitHandler: function ($form) {
            submitjob();
            return false;
        }

    });
```